# How to style certain posts differently in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, styles, posts

I am trying to achieve this particular layout for my posts on my blog page/homepage I hope this makes sense:

> |Most recent post fills whole content area| |2nd Post half the size|
>   |3rd post half the size| |4th Post half size| |5th post half size|
>   |6th post fills whole content area| |7th Post half size| |8th post
>   half size| |9th Post half size| |10th post half size| |11th post fills
>   whole content area| |12th Post half size| |13th post half size| |14th
>   Post half size| |15th post half size| |16th post fills whole content
>   area| |17th Post half size| |18th post half size| |19th Post half
>   size| |20th post half size|
>
> |Ajax Load Post Plugin goes here to load more posts|

I am currently using twenty twelve (child theme).

I have tried using the transformationpowertools method:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php $extra = ( $wp_query->current_post % 5 && !is_paged() ) ? 'specialclass' : ''; post_class($extra); ?>>
```

And this takes every 5 posts and assigns a class to the last 4 of them and this works great. However, when I float these classes left in my CSS so they display next to each other I cannot add a margin to the right of the first half sized post and the left of the second:

> |1st Half sized post|margin margin |2nd half sized post|

Unless there is something I am not thinking of I am going to have added one class to the half sized posts on the left and a separate class to the ones on the right:

> |Most recent post fills whole content area| |special class 1| |special
>   class 2| |special class 1| |special class 2| |6th post fills whole
>   content area| |special class 1| |special class 2| |special class 1|
>   |special class 2| |11th post fills whole content area| |special class
>   1| |special class 2| |special class 1| |special class 2| |16th post
>   fills whole content area| |special class 1| |special class 2| |special
>   class 1| |special class 2|

Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Comment: `<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php $extra = ( ( $wp_query->current_post % 5 == 0 && !is_paged() ) ? 'full' : 'half' ) . ( ( ( $wp_query->current_post % 5 == 1 || $wp_query->current_post % 5 == 3 ) && !is_paged() ) ? ' left' : '' ); post_class($extra); ?>>`

Comment: Special Thanks to the alchymyth for this solution!!

Comment: PS. The question above did not copy and paste properly so does not make a lot of sense. I also asked the question of the WordPress forums so check it out and it will make more sense: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/given-certain-posts-on-blog-page-their-own-class?replies=3#post-5170724